# Is the image of a small category small?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a [small category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+category), let $D$ be a [locally small category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+small+category). 
Given a functor $F:C\to D$, [the image of $F$ may not be a category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413138/can-it-happen-that-the-image-of-a-functor-is-not-a-category). Now [following the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+image#remarks), let's instead call the *image of $F$* the subcategory of $D$ generated by the images of the objects and morphisms of $C$ under $F$, i.e. close it under composition.

With this notion of image, by construction we have a subcategory of $D$. Is this subcategory again small?

Comment: Since $D$ is locally small, the image of $F$ should have a set of objects (the image of the set of objects of $C$, since $C$ is small and you can't reach any object outside that image) and each hom is a set (as a subset of the hom-set of locally-small $D$) so the image is small.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if $D$ isn't locally small, which is probably a more interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is trivial.  Every morphism in the image of $F$ can be written as a finite composition of morphisms that come from morphisms of $C$, and there is only a small set of such finite compositions.

Comment: Another way to put this is that the image of $F$ is a quotient of the category freely generated by the underlying graph of $C$, which certainly remains small.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: I think you mean the underlying graph of the "naive" image of $F$ (which is not necessarily actually a subcategory).

Comment: Sure, let's say that.